# how to programatically activate form in vb6

Tags: vb6

I am building VB6.0 application , where is user swipes the card and form will kind of pops out with a Thank you message. Rest all are working fine , only thing is the form gets minimized, rather it should pop out.
I googled theirs Form.Activate but when I write it gives error.

> Compile Error : Method or data member not found

I am new to VB so please excuse if any naive mistake.
 Code:

```
  Me.Hide
  Form2.Show
  Form2.Activate
```

I need Form2 to Pop out.

Thanks

Comment: You've built a rep in the 70's and don't know better than to not show us your code?

Comment: Theirs nothing particular in code, however I have added it.

Comment: There is no `Activate` method available on `Form`s in VB6, unlike in VBA for some objects. You are mixing up something.

Comment: oh i thought so , any other alternative ?

Comment: @MicSim any suggestion I have tried lot but no go , my main form is in Invisible running in background. please help

Comment: `Form.Show` should be enough to show the form. You could try a `Form.Show vbModal` or just show a plain message box with your message..

Answer (score 0):

I am able to achieve by

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

Dim lR As Long
     lR = SetTopMostWindow(Form2.hwnd, True)

End Sub
```

and added a module

```
Option Explicit
 Public Const SWP_NOMOVE = 2
 Public Const SWP_NOSIZE = 1
 Public Const FLAGS = SWP_NOMOVE Or SWP_NOSIZE
 Public Const HWND_TOPMOST = -1
 Public Const HWND_NOTOPMOST = -2

 Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib &quot;user32&quot; _
       (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
       ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Long, _
       ByVal x As Long, _
       ByVal y As Long, _
       ByVal cx As Long, _
       ByVal cy As Long, _
       ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long

 Public Function SetTopMostWindow(hwnd As Long, Topmost As Boolean) _
    As Long

    If Topmost = True Then &#39;Make the window topmost
       SetTopMostWindow = SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, _
          0, FLAGS)
    Else
       SetTopMostWindow = SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, _
          0, 0, FLAGS)
       SetTopMostWindow = False
    End If
 End Function</pre>
```

One can refer to https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/184297

Thanks